# PHP banner com FlexSlider

Tags: php, jquery

Estou criando em PHP uma exibição de banners com o uso de FlexSlider. Porém quando carrego a página de exemplo que estou testando, não aparece absolutamente nada. O que pode estar errado? O arquivo php, as imagens e os arquivos flexslider.css, jquery.flexslider.js e jquery.flexslider-min.js estão todos na mesma pasta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
    });
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flexslider">

  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="Imagem1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="Imagem2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="Imagem3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Faltou só o jquery,

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` que deve vir antes de tudo.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado! Porém, o banner está em tela cheia, de que forma posso definir um tamanho menor e posicioná-lo? E é possível incluir um link para cada imagem? Assim, ao ser clicada, uma nova página é aberta.